# Where should the error appear for a stylesheet typo in a react app?

Tags: reactjs

First off; I have corrected the misspelt stylesheet name and my app works, now, I just need to find the error.

I'm working through the Pro MERN Stack, 2nd Edition book and I have completed up to the Server Router section in Chapter 12.

When testing the server-rendered About page it is obvious that it hasn't been styled in line with the browser rendered page.

Express routes **localhost:8000/about** to render()

```
function render(req, res) {
  // const body = ReactDOMServer.renderToString(<About />);
  const element = (
    <StaticRouter location={req.url} context={{}}>
      <Page />
    </StaticRouter>
  );
  const body = ReactDOMServer.renderToString(element);
  res.send(template(body));
}
```

the template function is as follows:

```
export default function template(body) {
  return `<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Pro MERN Title</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/boostrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" ></link>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"></meta>

    <style>...</style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <!-- Page generated from template. -->
    <div id="contents">${body}</div>

    <script src="/env.js"></script>
    <script src="/vendor.bundle.js"></script>
    <script src="/app.bundle.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
`;
}
```

the error is that `href="/boostrap/css/bootstrap.min.css"`
is missing a 't' in the word boo**t**strap.

The question is where should I look for any error?

Added in response to question about 404 ...
[image]

Comment: Sounds like there should be a 404 in the network tab

Comment: Good point, but as you can see from the added image ...